# Safari NotSupportedError Custom Element in shadowRoot.innerHTML in constructor of parent Custom Element

Tags: safari, web-component, custom-element, domexception

I'm creating a custom element and setting its shadowRoot to include other custom elements, which throws `NotSupportedError (DOM Exception 9): A newly constructed custom element must not have child nodes`. (Note that it doesn't throw the error when there is no child custom-element in the markup.)

Is there an appropriate way to change my constructor so that I don't throw this `NotSupportedError` in Safari?

Is there a better way to setup this elements and its content?

Why is this happening only when I have another custom element within its markup?

Thanks. The following is an excerpt of the relevant work.

```
class MyControl extends HTMLElement{
constructor(){
    super();

    var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<slot name=form><select-provider src="/path/to/endpoint"></select-provider></slot>
`;
}
}
customElements.define('my-control', MyControl);
class SelectProvider extends HTMLElement{
constructor(){
    super();

    var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<slot></slot>
`;
}
/* omitted handling of src, loading url */
render(){/* rewrite select with options */}
}
customElements.define('select-provider', SelectProvider);
</script>
<my-control><span>this custom element throws and error in Safari</span></my-control>
```

Comment: Your slot tag should be empty as they are insertion points.

Comment: @Supersharp The content in the slot is the default content when no content is provided. In other words this is valid and desired use, and the reason the slot is named. Are you seeing `NotSupportedError`s disappear with slot adjustments along the lines of what you're suggesting?

Comment: You're right but when you remove it, do you still get the error in Safari ?

Comment: @Supersharp yes, the error goes away, but not when the slot is empty, only when the slot no longer has a custom element. Said another way: I can put any markup in the slot, but when it has another custom element, this error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

My child `select-provider` was doing a `this.appendChild` in the constructor which throws this error. Otherwise it works as expected. To resolve I simply moved this into the `connectedCallback`.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you did? Where can you define the `connectedCallback`?

Comment: And...this is the link I was looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks

Comment: This has also been very helpful to me in my work with web components: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/
including the best practices. the key takeaways related to the original question is generally to avoid changing anything (no DOM changes) to the custom element except the shadowRoot, can do anything in the constructor. I usually add event listeners to the custom element and populate the shadowRoot in my constructors, in the connected callbacks handle any more elaborate rendering/dom/events that affect the non-shadow dom.